# How to write a Query so that based on a Date, it takes data for the next 7 days

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a Calendar from which I need to pick a date so when a date is picked, the query should show all the data for that date & also for the next 7 days.

My current Query is as below, but it only shows the data for the date that's been picked.

```
SELECT MailDate, Status, JobNo
FROM Table_1
WHERE MailDate=@MailDate
```

Please help me out with this. I'm using SQL SERVER 2008

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Select MailDate, Status, JobNo FROM Table_1 WHERE MailDate BETWEEN @MailDate AND @MailDate + 7`

May or may not work, you didn't tell us what sql engine we're talking about.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

SQL Server:

```
SELECT MailDate, Status, JobNo FROM Table_1 WHERE MailDate >= @MailDate AND MailDate < DATEADD(day,7,@MailDate)
```

Mysql:

```
SELECT MailDate, Status, JobNo FROM Table_1 WHERE MailDate >= @MailDate AND MailDate < DATE_ADD(@MailDate, INTERVAL 7 DAY)
```

Comment: oops. on your MySQL version... you have it as 1 day interval, not 7

Comment: `Between` is a much better way to write these queries when it is available. Check it out.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write the query to reflect both the current date and the next 7 days.

To do this, your date format in the DB should be a UNIX Timestamp.

```
SELECT MailDate, Status, JobNo FROM Table_1 WHERE MailDate = @MailDate AND MailDate < (time + 7 days)
```